# Using video background in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background

As the question suggests, how do I do it? I'm using version 3.3.1 .I have a video file inside my website which located in

```
http://localhost/app_portal/public/img/RooftopClouds.mp4
```

When I check it on the browser it plays fine. But when I use it as a background, it doesn't work. Here's what I've done so far, I have `app.css` I use the same layout as laravel is using in Larvel 5.

```
body {
 margin: 0;
 background: url('http://localhost/app_portal/public/img/RooftopClouds.mp4');
}
```

Do I need to configure something else? Thanks

Comment: Have you got result then accept answer for help others

Answer (score 0):

> HTML

```
<!-- Warming Up -->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Buenard:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="http://pupunzi.com/mb.components/mb.YTPlayer/demo/inc/jquery.mb.YTPlayer.js"></script>

<!--Video Section-->
<section class="content-section video-section">
  <div class="pattern-overlay">
  <a id="bgndVideo" class="player" data-property="{videoURL:'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fdJc1_IBKJA',containment:'.video-section', quality:'large', autoPlay:true, mute:true, opacity:1}">bg</a>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1>Full Width Video</h1>  
        <h3>Enjoy Adding Full Screen Videos to your Page Sections</h3>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

> CSS

```
.video-section .pattern-overlay {
background-color: rgba(71, 71, 71, 0.59);
padding: 110px 0 32px;
min-height: 496px; 
/* Incase of overlay problems just increase the min-height*/
}
.video-section h1, .video-section h3{
text-align:center;
color:#fff;
}
.video-section h1{
font-size:110px;
font-family: 'Buenard', serif;
font-weight:bold;
text-transform: uppercase;
margin: 40px auto 0px;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
-webkit-text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
-moz-text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
}
.video-section h3{
font-size: 25px;
font-weight:lighter;
margin: 0px auto 15px;
}
.video-section .buttonBar{display:none;}
.player {font-size: 1px;}
```

> JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".player").mb_YTPlayer();

});
```